# How to trim NSString to 11 characters and add '…' to the end

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a String that I want to trim, if it has more than 11 characters.
If this is the case, it should be trimmed to 11 characters and a '…' should be appended!
What would u suggest is the best practice for that?
I came accross `stringByPaddingToLength` But maybe theres a better way!
Thx in advance!

Comment: May i suggest that if it's longer than 11 characters, you trim it to 10 and add … ? Otherwise it will be 12 characters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about

```
if (myString.length > 11)
    myString = [[myString substringToIndex:11] stringByAppendingString:@"…"];
```

Comment: oops, thanks Regexident - I got some capitalisation wrong as well :(

Comment: Had pretty much the same answer short to submitting. Figured it would make more fixing yours than posting a basically duplicate answer myself. ;)